# *Solution* ConfBridge - How to start recording when marked user enters conference

Tags: asterisk

This is a solution to a problem that I searched unsuccessfully for an answer to. Ended up creating the following. Thought I'd share.

With confbridge record_conference=yes the recording will start with *any* caller - even if they have to wait for marked user to enter conference. So how to start recording when marked user enters?

The following config achieves this by:

- record_conference=yes starts recording when normal user enters
- when marked user (admin user) enters, the dialplan:

  - stops the recording
  - deletes any existing recording (in this case I only want a single recording file - another script will take a copy of whatever is there at the end of the conference - this gets around having to know the    random digits that confbridge adds to the filename - because there will only be one file present!)
  - starts recording
- if marked user is the first to enter, the stop & start will fail because the conference isn't active yet and the record_conference=yes
  will start the recording instead

Config below.

Regards,

Richard.

```
/etc/asterisk/confbridge.conf
[default_bridge]
type=bridge
record_conference=yes

[admin_user]
type=user
admin=yes     
marked=yes    

[default_user]
type=user
startmuted=yes;
music_on_hold_when_empty=yes
quiet=yes     
wait_marked=yes   
dsp_drop_silence=yes 

/etc/asterisk/extensions.conf
exten => 8003,1,Set(CONFBRIDGE(bridge,record_file)=/var/spool/asterisk/confbridge/meeting.wav)
exten => 8003,2,System(asterisk -x 'confbridge record stop 9001')
exten => 8003,3,System(rm /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/*)
exten => 8003,4,System(rm /var/spool/asterisk/confbridge/*)
exten => 8003,5,System(asterisk -x 'confbridge record start 9001')
exten => 8003,6,ConfBridge(9001,,admin_user)
```

Comment: This solution is very bad quality.  1) it use system commands, which are really not secure 2) it use full wildcard(*) on delete. 3) it delete other recordings like freepbx ones. 4) it do not really track enter of user. So you can easy lost conference reording by re-connection.